# Why do i need a conditional type constraint when i already have the same constraint in the type arguments

Tags: typescript

In the example below i need an additional conditional constraint in `PersonListProps` to be able to get the correct type on the control prop.

```
type PersonListProps<FormType extends GenericFormData> = {
  control: FormType extends GenericFormData ? Control<FormType> : never;
};

export function PersonList<FormType extends GenericFormData>(
  props: PersonListProps<FormType>
): React.ReactElement {
  const { fields } = useFieldArray({
    name: "persons",
    control: props.control
  });

  return (
    <>
      {fields.map((item) => {
        return <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>;
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Why isn't the constraint in the type args sufficient enough to make typescript understand that FormType is in fact extending GenericFormData?

```
type PersonListProps<FormType extends GenericFormData> = {
  control: Control<FormType>;
};
```

In case the question so far has been a bit unclear this is the gist of it:
Why do i need `FormType extends GenericFormData ? Control<FormType> : never;` in addition to `FormType extends GenericFormData` for it to recognize `"persons"` as a valid name?

Here is a codesandbox if anyone wants to have a closer look:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rhf-generic-field-array-forked-fmc340?file=/src/PersonList.tsx:152-626

It made sense for me to put it there while developing but i got a question about why it was necessary and wasn't able to find a good explanation.

Thanks in advance for all answers :)

[Minimal reproducible example:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhhB7AJgU0gMwE7wLaQDYCWARpAM4AuAhhuVCMOOQJ4AOqAYgcnogGqV4ArslKQAvJABKyAMbwMiADwUMBAHYBzADSRKapgD4A3OGDAAKgAsCom7rIFsLQmgIzK5AvDWR4aSOSWqAAKHpYBrKiYOAFB%20MQAdIyRkKGBiuYG4pDmkMgAHuTIaoiiekyQAPyQANbITH45kABckGrIAG7IGCbMbJCc3IhplhmDPPxCInmFxaUDXBMCwqRZEiNji3zLIsbJ-Qhq5Fh4m0OTK2uQAN7g4AC%20JgUs8uSQKDJ41FGCajKe3kgglIyEOx3geDw3TOSymogKRRKonG2zh2RRFxEOnMADlKNhUAi5sithtzBidqt0aSwjDUZcDAAKFhYFikVrXORHE7NMEnOmY1Y6NT45DNXGi%204ASmaHXgBEQpjAdDgSCiWFwhBIczoDHA6iKGDQlBkqAA4sVum52PJsAARDyUG5QSCutgYUjedlkY7qDQAbQAug87nc%20qgAOryGp%204LdT1qAAyNnIwVZpEUNow2HMKSJSMgFvaqhkWftjqut1dZkgEcsFUQ8EgBDayGQiFidi5iAI5G8AkgXJUlANkAA7kEfIFUOHqBpIIAwal0eAwyEoiAqXa9xxH7Q7fcLlpLZYdVBdXPBeFaZdz-Xz8yLVtLttPTuqfIhmdtt%20QWVa7S6HoHhMcAhzeMdoz9bIv2zH8ZkRB8j2tF8K0gRkXU5bxL3uVoowwGNNDjD1vGTCg03gNkYJzSIDHAKVxCyZ1q2ASAcSbbosAwF1gVBLCTihDBGUw7kIWFUVmgAIndBNSAk6U7nuUMawAUXyfFnFQCdulQXtm1ENR4HAyDNH2VA2PIPCCI0IiE1I1N0youD71ER9jxQqhK3PPiIVaD9ThvGjgLuMC2kMyyoIkRy81mAtXOQ7NXyydDXWE7DWnM8LCPjEiU3IyiArYWj6LERjbhrOCAHIpOytRZIqvTQreShSFIAgNBFIgoQCJtw0gCqNgK38KoSRkACYAGZRtGqVwB4vyBKEi8TjEglJOkr05JmkNwCAA)

```
/**
 * Code from lib start
 */
type FieldValues = Record<string, any>;
//This is a simplification of the Path type from the lib.
type Path<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type FieldPath<TFieldValues extends FieldValues> = Path<TFieldValues>;
type Control<TFieldValues> = {

};
export declare function useController<TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues, TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>>(props: {control:Control<TFieldValues>, name:TName}):void
/**
 * Code from lib end
 */

interface GenericFormData {
    persons: string[]
}

type WorkingPersonListProps<FormType extends GenericFormData> = {
  // Why do i need this conditonal constraint when the typearg ⬆ already is constrained to GenericFormData
  control: FormType extends GenericFormData ? Control<FormType> : never;
};

const working = <FormType extends GenericFormData> (
  {control}: WorkingPersonListProps<FormType>
) =>  {
  // No error
  useController({control, name:"persons"})

}

// Example where it is not working
type NotWorkingPersonListProps<FormType extends GenericFormData> = {
  control: Control<FormType>
};

const notWorking = <FormType extends GenericFormData> (
  {control}: NotWorkingPersonListProps<FormType>
) =>  {
// Type '"persons"' is not assignable to type 'Path<FormType>'.(2322)
useController({control, name:"persons"})

}
```

Comment: I don't think you need a "conditional type constraint"; it's just that a generic conditional type causes has different *inference* behavior when you call `useController()`.  You can make the not-working version work if you manually specify the generic, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAdkZN).  So the premise of the question doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: How should we proceed? Do you want an answer to the question as asked (which is that the inferred type arguments are different) or do you want to [edit] the question to ask *why* the inference is different (which is probably much fiddlier to answer authoritatively)?